# load data on SAP IQ using python + sqlanydb. 'Operation failed on file due to file permissions

Tags: python, sybase, sqlanydb

I'm trying to make a quick file upload to a table via python on SAP IQ. Faced such a problem. Initially, the user has access to download files using  `load table (...) using client file ...` instruction. If you use the software from SAP (interactive sql) everything works fine, but using the sqlanydb library I get an error `... (b'Operation failed on file due to file permissions.) File: file.txt \ n-- (oslib / hos_clientfileio.cxx 143 ) '`, -1006148). Help please understand, what exactly am I doing wrong? Probably it is necessary to add some  parameter in `sqlanydb.connect ()`, but i could not find the normal documentation. I can not use `import` or `insert`, because files can getting larger in the future (from 100K lines and more). So `load table (...) using client file` instruction has very quickly uploading data and practically makes no effort on server. 
My code:

```
import sqlanydb

conne = sqlanydb.connect(uid='user',
                         pwd='password',
                         databasename = 'dbname',
                         host = 'host.name')

_SQL = '''create table #REP001 (
                       col1 int,
                       col2 int
                     )
;
commit;

load table #REP001
(
  col1 ';',
  col2 '\x0d\x0a'
)
using client file 'file.txt'
            quotes off
            escapes off
;
commit;'''

cur = conne.cursor()
cur.execute(_SQL)

cur.close()
conne.close()
```

I'm ready to use any idea, maybe there are other libraries that will make this possible using python